# git repack: segregating by file type & configuring packs by group?

Tags: git

Is there a way to tell Git to create packfiles based on file types, and to specify the delta-ification and zlib compression for those classes / types?

I have a rather large repository, much of which is composed of image assets and translation files (.po), the latter actually being the largest fraction of the working copy *and* the repository data.

- For the image assets, neither delta nor zlib compression are useful: the images are already compress (so they don't compress well under zlib) and delta compression does nothing useful when small changes tend to cascade through the compressed image (and are rare anyway, usually once the asset is committed it's either left alone forever or replaced wholesale).
- For the PO files, while they're technically text files I would expect them to delta-compress very badly for this specific repository: the historical generator / exporter would export the translations in essentially random order so from one export to the next it's as if the entire file has been rewritten.

As a result, when the repository is repacked I'd like to try packing the images together neither delta-compress nor zlib-compress them, and the PO files together and zlib-compress them (at the maximum possible level) but not delta-compress them. This way they ought not waste cycles on useless compression work, and should avoid polluting the compression of more "normal" code files.

However my previous experiments in packfiles did not go well. Is there builtin support for this sort of segregation & configuration which I missed, or would I need to build the packs by hand using low-level commands or even libgit2 directly?

Comment: If the order within the `.po` files amounts essentially random lines of text, you may also want to consider adding a githook to sort their contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by driving `git pack-objects` manually.

To create a pack file with just your PNG files, you would do:

```
git rev-list --objects --all | fgrep .png |
    git -c core.compression=0 pack-objects .git/objects/pack/pack-png
```

That creates a pack file that contains only blobs whose file names contain `.png`.

The previous invocation has printed an SHA1 to the console, call it `$packid`. To avoid that future repacking will destroy your pack, you can mark it to be kept:

```
touch .git/objects/pack/pack-png-$packid.keep
```

A subsequent

```
git repack
```

should collect your remaining objects into a new pack file that does not contain any of the PNG files.

Note though, that the example of `git rev-list` above does not walk through your commits held in the reflogs. That is, PNG files that are used in temporarily held commits that are not also used in permanent commits count as "your remaing objects".

Answer (score 4):

Alas, no: the controls available are only the following:

- `core.bigFileThreshold`: files that exceed this size are not packed, merely zlib-compressed.
- `pack.island` and several related settings: these set up so-called delta islands, as described in [the `git pack-objects` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects).

These do not come anywhere close to what you want.  (Note: there is also `core.compression` and two related items, but these are strictly global, not per-object.)

Comment: Thanks, that sadly confirms my findings (I'd previously experimented with delta islands but that's not really the axis I'm looking for).